# KeyError: "['Hours', 'Game'] not in index"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have error to select my columns hours and game

I have tried different codes but none of them are working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# upload the dataset to spyder
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Documents/FYP II/gamedataset.csv")

# Data selection on columns needed for data mining

collect =  data[['Game','Genre','price','Hours','Day.period','Age','Gender','Violence.Rate','Cause.gaming','CID.Rating',]]
```

i expect a dataset collect to show

i get:

```
KeyError: "['Hours', 'Game'] not in index
```

[image]

Comment: show the .csv...

Comment: (Or a portion of the dataframe.)

Comment: Add output of `data.columns`

Comment: Ensure that there are no spaces before/after the column name.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack OVerflow. When asking a pandas question, please do not add screenshots; instead, create a minimal dataframe that reproduces the problem, and show that instead. In your example, show (with re-creating code) the first two or three rows of the dataframe and the relevant columns; you don't need a big dataframe to recreate the problem. To learn more, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Check `data.columns` and compare 'Hours' and 'Game' column name. It is quite possible that there is an added space in column name.